# Wie sagt man "at your own time" auf Deutsch?

Tags: grammar, english-to-german

> Arbeitest du zu deiner eigenen Zeit?  (Ich versuche *Do you work at your own time?* zu übersetzen.)

Wie sagt man *at your own time* auf Deutsch? Ich weiß nicht, ob *zu deiner eignen Zeit* hier richtig ist.

Comment: Do you mean "on your own time" or "at your own pace"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not aware of a fixed translation for *at your own time*.

You could translate *Do you work at your own time?* as follows:

> Kannst du deine Arbeitszeit *flexibel gestalten*?
>
> Hast du eine *flexible Arbeitszeit*? (or *flexible Arbeitszeitregelung*)

In other settings, e.g. learning, a translation like *nach dem eigenen Zeitplan*, *nach dem eigenen Takt* or – more colloquial – *wenn es (zeitlich) passt* can be used.

Comment: Passt hier eventuell auch "Gleitzeit"?

Comment: @Wolf Good point!